# Всплывающая подсказка

Tags: delphi

Как сделать  всплывающую подсказку в Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

Cвойство компонента **ShowHint** устанавливаем в **1**
Пишем подсказку в свойстве **Hint**

При наведении на компонент, будет всплывать подсказка.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Задайте свойство `Hint` у интересующего компонента.

Answer (score 0):

Бывают также варианты многострочного Hint, но для этого надо код писать соответственный.

```
Button1.Hint := 'Line 1' + #13#10+'Line 2';
```

Естественно включать свойство ShowHint на true;